# Я иду-иду-иду(:) напеваю ерунду!

Tags: пунктуация, поэзия

> Я иду-иду-иду(:) напеваю ерунду!

Можно между "иду" дефисы поставить?

Можно ли поставить двоеточие?
(Как именно иду? Напеваю ерунду!)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146597/discussion-on-question-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 3):

**Выбираем дефисное или раздельное написание** (для *иду-иду-иду*)

**1. Правила Розенталя по теме**

[§ 16. Запятая при повторяющихся словах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105#pp105)

1. **Запятая** ставится между повторяющимися словами, произносимыми с интонацией перечисления и обозначающими: 1) **длительность действия**: Но он ехал, ехал, а Жадрина было не видать (П.); Зимы ждала, ждала природа (П.); Сапожник бился, бился и наконец за ум хватился (Кр.) А я сидел, сидел, слушал, слушал (Т.);

[§ 17. Дефисное написание повторяющихся слов](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106)

1. Между двумя повторяющимися словами пишется **дефис**, если образуется сложное слово (обычно с одним фонетическим ударением). Сюда относятся: 2) глаголы со значением **непрерывности процесса или интенсивности действия:** На самой заре встанешь и топчешься-топчешься по избе: и воды надо принести, и печь растопить (Пауст.); сидел-сидел в напрасном ожидании; просил-просил о помощи;

**2. В приведенном предложении АВТОРСКОЕ решение**

Можно обозначить запятыми длительность действия или дефисом  непрерывность действия, при этом учитываем фонетику (перечисление или слитное произношение), но потом скорректируем его при необходимости. По стилю и структуре больше подходит **дефисное** написание.

Примечание.  В правилах нет примеров с дефисным написанием  вида ***иду-иду-иду*** (из трех слов), существуют ли вообще такие слова?

В реальной жизни они точно есть.  Вот в парке папа катает маленькую девочку в коляске-велосипеде  (двухместный такой экипаж), и та увлеченно командует: «Крути-крути-крутИ!».  Эмоции,  экспрессия, интенсивность движения. (И интонацию маленькие дети обычно выбирают правильную, почти  по Розенталю.)

**Можно ли использовать двоеточие?**

**1. Вот с двоеточием никак не получается**

Пояснение в общем случае связано с раскрытием содержания всего сообщения или отдельных слов (***а именно***), но здесь такой необходимости нет. Также (по правилам Розенталя) при пояснительных отношениях обычно используется союзная связь.
[Розенталь § 23. Пояснительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119)

**Примечание.** После сказуемого, выраженного глаголом, двоеточие обычно ставится после обобщающего слова  перед однородным рядом: *Отец совершил несколько будничных движений: достал бумажник, порылся в нём, извлёк две старые трёшницы, получил билеты* (Наг.). В этом случае однородный ряд "поясняет" обобщающее слово (раскрывает его содержание).

**2. Похожий пример с двоеточием**

Для постановки двоеточия фразу нужно изменить, например:

***Я иду-иду-иду, а какая я иду? Я веселая иду: напеваю ерунду!***
Теперь мы раскрываем содержание сказанного: Я какая? Я веселая. Как именно это можно определить? Напеваю что-то.

**3. Об интонации**

При постановке двоеточия применяется **пояснительная интонация** (интонационное предупреждение по Розенталю). Это неполное понижение голоса и подчеркнутая пауза.

Двоеточие можно заменить **тире** и использовать **присоединительную интонацию** (полное понижение голоса и меньшая пауза, чем при двоеточии). Если паузу еще уменьшить, то ставим присоединительную запятую: *Я веселая иду — напеваю ерунду! Я веселая иду, напеваю ерунду!*

Три интонационных варианта **похожи** (понижение голоса перед паузой различной длительности), поэтому часто **заменяют** друг друга. (Описание интонации  взято из учебника для педвузов "Синтаксис современного русского языка".)

**Вывод**

Заданное предложение можно записать так: ***Я иду-иду-иду, // напеваю ерунду!***

Возможен и другой вариант: *Я иду, иду, иду, // напеваю ерунду!*
Но при такой записи сложнее выбрать правильную интонацию, так как при чтении желательно разделить фразу на две части.

Comment: Весёлость не выражается в напевании ерунды. И надо поставить "весёлая" перед двоеточием, а то опять глагол раскрывается. Вы не написали, почему дефисное.

Comment: oleedd, давайте так. Про дефисное написание сами уж прочитайте, про веселость подумайте (интересная тема!), а про именное сказуемое я вам скажу. Я веселая иду: у меня это предикативная основа, глагол движения и признак. И bye bye (пока-пока).

Comment: Не "сами уж прочитайте", а на данном сайте необходимо аргументировать, вы же просто привели правило с обоими вариантами. Нарушаете правила сайта... Про весёлость сразу подумал, так не работает. Разве то, что человек напевает ерунду, означает, что он весёлый? Разве напевание ерунды — показатель весёлости? Нет. Вы сказали, что раскрывается "весёлая", а при таком порядке "весёлая иду" раскрывается.

Comment: oleedd ну что же мы как в школе... Написала ведь: "В приведенном предложении АВТОРСКОЕ РЕШЕНИЕ. Можно обозначить запятыми длительность действия или дефисом непрерывность действия".  Куда понятнее-то? Поэтому все-таки bye bye. Кстати, вы, вероятно, никогда не нарушаете правила сайта...Или у вас двойные стандарты.

Comment: Вы не написали, почему выбираете дефисное. И у вас структура наизнанку. Зачем писать причину через 5 километров? Или пишите свой вариант после обоснования. Разница не только в том, о чём сказал Розенталь. Произношение очень отличается, а у вас будто нет. Это не то, что можно взаимозаменять. Ваш пример с "весёлая" притянут за уши.

Comment: "Ваш пример с "весёлая" притянут за уши."   Это просторечно-экспрессивная критика... Хороших слов Вы не понимаете, переходим к официальному формату общения.

Comment: Нет, так говорят, когда что-то не на своём месте. Не вижу в этом ничего обидного. Вот вы взяли исходный пример и притянули к нему двоеточие, добавив "весёлая". Ну не имеет напевание ерунды отношения к весёлости, можно и грустно напевать ерунду. Никто не поймёт, что раскрывается "весёлая", больше похоже на указание причины (весёлая из-за этого).

Comment: Раскрытие должно быть ясным и логичным.